# localhost/requestflowtest

Tags: php

I am new to magento I type the following code below and the url was localhost/requestflowtest but i got 404 error even i tried with localhost/magento1.9.0.1/requestflowtest plz could anyone guide me

Practice_ControllerTest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <config> <modules> <Practice_ControllerTest> <active>true</active> <codePool>local</codePool> </Practice_ControllerTest> </modules> </config>
```

In  `app/code/local/Practice/ControllerTest/controllers/IndexController.php`

```
<?php class Practice_ControllerTest_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action { public function indexAction() { echo '<h1>Hello World</h1>'; } }
```

In `/var/www/html/app/code/local/Practice/ControllerTest/etc/config.xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config> 
     <modules> 
         <Practice_ControllerTest> 
            <version>0.0.1</version> 
         </Practice_ControllerTest> 
     </modules> 
     <frontend>
         <routers> 
             <test_controller> 
                 <use>standard</use> 
                 <args> 
                     <module>Practice_ControllerTest</module> 
                     <frontName>requestflowtest</frontName> 
                 </args> 
             </test_controller> 
         </routers> 
     </frontend> 
 </config>
```

Comment: try localhost/html in your browser address bar

Comment: what you getting

Comment: Sir i am getting 404 error

Comment: you have to create some folder under /var/www/html/magento/ and under this folder you all magento folders will go and you need to access like localhost/magento

Comment: my localhost is working with localhost / url and with localhost/index.php

Comment: yes correct it will work with localhost but best practise is create some folder and under that your magento folders will go and you should have to access localhost/magentofolder

Comment: Sir becoz of this exception i used localhost/requestflow as it was given in material

Comment: visit llink:-http://www.mcamaterialany.blogspot.com